# PIG HbaseStorage -LTE doesn't yield any results

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig

I'm using a Pig Script to list rows in hbase.  I can use the -gte option to get rows that are greater than a certain value.  However whenever I use -lte (by itself or paired with a -gte) I get zero records back.

```
--this works returns many rows
LOAD 'hbase://TABLE' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('CF:I','-loadKey true -caster HBaseBinaryConverter -gte \\x00\\x00\x01\x2C') AS (product_id:bytearray);

--this returns 0 rows
--and there are rows that would be less than this value
LOAD 'hbase://TABLE' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('CF:I','-loadKey true -caster HBaseBinaryConverter -lte \\x00\\x00\x01\x2D') AS (product_id:bytearray);
```

Comment: Sorry to ask the obvious... but do you actually have keys that are less than that?

Comment: @Donald Miner yes I do because the first load actually returns values in fact for the second load if I change -lte to -gte I also get values.